# Delphi - When the scrolling has finished

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Is there any windows message which can be used to indicate that scrolling on a TScrollBox has been finished? I need to do some custom operations when an user is scrolling through a TScrollBox, and until now I've caught the WM_VSCROLL message and do the operations, but since the operations became more and more complex I would like to execute them only when the user has finished scrolling. MSDN documentation does not indicate that such a message exists(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff486024(v=vs.85).aspx) or maybe I'm looking into the wrong place.

Comment: Can you use OnMouseUp to identify end of scrolling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you link to tells you the answer. While the user is scrolling — that is, dragging the thumb around — the low-order word of the `wParam` message parameter will be `sb_ThumbTrack`. When the user finishes scrolling — releases the thumb — it will be `sb_ThumbPosition` instead.

The other methods of scrolling do not have a start and end; they are all distinct events that might occur repeatedly. There's no way to tell which of them is the last in a series of repeated events without peering into the future.